# My Minecraft skin won't change from Alex or Steve even though I've changed it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I've had Minecraft for the longest time and have NEVER had this problem. I've done everything I've seen others do, I've uninstalled and reinstalled Minecraft, I've changed my skin in Minecraft main site but still nothing. My launcher and the Minecraft site both say it's changed and is being used, but when I load up a world it converts back to Alex, or Steve. This is making me really frustrated and I would like any help I can get.

I use a MacBook. My launcher for Minecraft is up to date to it's in 1.18.2, and I just don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Have you tried waiting? (Or clearing your cache?)

Comment: @aytimothy I have nothing has worked so far

Comment: are you connected to the internet when you load up the world?

Comment: @Esther yes I am I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Head to a third-party Minecraft skin website like Minecraft Skins and download the skin you’d like to apply to your character. Make a note of where the downloaded file is stored (usually the Downloads folder).
Head to the Minecraft website.
Click the Menu icon and select Profile to log in with the account associated with Minecraft on your PC.
Click the Browse button, select the file you downloaded earlier and click Open.
Click Save to upload your custom skin.

Comment: I have that's how I've been getting my skins, and that's how I've been applying them, I download them from Minecraft skins the skindex one, I always have and I've tried a different one to and nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to the internet and you can play on servers but the problem is only with your skin, then I may have found a solution.

I'm not sure about MacOS but on Windows I used this to fix it:
I navigated to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and there is a hosts file. I copied the file to the .minecraft folder (the location of the game)

That seemed to have fixed the authentication issues with the skin server and my skin finally showed up.

Comment: Why would copying the hosts file to .minecraft would fix the problem though? That's system file of Windows, it doesn't have anything to do with Minecraft (and Minecraft doesn't care even if it was in .minecraft) unless you (or some illegal third party software) modified contents inside hosts file. Just by copying to .minecraft wouldn't do anything, unless you've moved the file, not copied it (so that Windows assumes that hosts is missing and recreates without any modify, in other words resets to factory default). What exactly is written in your hosts file, both .minecraft one and \etc one?